# No Overload Matches; TypeScript and Generic Method

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I've defined the following interface type:

```ts
interface Input<TOutput> { }
```

And the following extension of that interface type:

```ts
interface ExampleInput extends Input<ExampleOutput> { }

interface ExampleOutput { }
```

I've also defined the following "service" interface:

```ts
interface Service {
  invoke<TInput extends Input<TOutput>, TOutput>(input: TInput): Observable<TOutput>
}
```

However, when I try to call it with an instance of `ExampleInput`, it fails:

```ts
function example(service: Service) {
  service.invoke({} as ExampleInput).subscribe((output: ExampleOutput) => {
    console.log(output);
  });
}
```

```text
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<unknown>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(output: ExampleOutput) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<unknown>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: unknown) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(output: ExampleOutput) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'output' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ExampleOutput'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: unknown) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(output: ExampleOutput) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'output' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ExampleOutput'.

185   service.invoke({} as ExampleInput).subscribe((output: ExampleOutput) => {
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

Why is the return type of the `Observable`'s `subscribe` callback either `unknown` or `void`, when I'd expect it to be `ExampleOutput`?

---

Elaborating with a different language example, in JVM Kotlin, the following compiles and behaves as expected (*with the appropriate implementaions to actually run*)

```kotlin
fun interface Subscriber<TOutput>
{
    fun subscribe(callback: (output: TOutput) -> Unit): Unit
}

interface Input<TOutput>

interface ExampleInput : Input<ExampleOutput>

interface ExampleOutput

interface Service
{
    fun <TInput : Input<TOutput>, TOutput> invoke(input: TInput): Subscriber<TOutput>
}

fun example(service: Service)
{
    service.invoke(object : ExampleInput { }).subscribe { output: ExampleOutput ->
        println(output)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently with you definition

```js
interface Service {
  invoke<TInput extends Input<TOutput>, TOutput>(input: TInput): Observable<TOutput>
}
```

it's defining a method that accepts an argument that has to have the properties of `Input<TOutput>` and the returned type is unknown because you haven't passed value for it. To do so you can invoke it by

```js
service.invoke<string, number>.subscribe()
```

---

Probably you'd want to describe your service interface as with generics in the service as probably there the type is known

```js
interface Service<O> {
  invoke(input: Input<O>): Observable<O>
}
```

```js
function example(service: Service<ExampleOutput>) {
  service.invoke({}).subscribe((output) => {
    console.log(output);
  });
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FcwB4AqA8jtmAHzIDeyAvgFAD0DyAgiACbJgAWKMA9gBtB-AO6gA5sggAPSCADOwfiGT8YXbnDDJQkWIhRgAnhggAuOnT3R4SZAFEZcALYZBEdKWlyIHBWiYOLhOru4QxGCkFNT01uC2ho7Obh6R3rGMzKgA5ABuKHCCCvzI7BAwoBCcPHxCIuIgUgBECtB5wEjNugkGSJZWNn0ohABGbVB5cKMeBDF0yMgKWOMIUMCjFsgAFAhFgqOIANbmO-wkOKf4AJTIALwUefzA7LcPyE8vdHEgrhAKGCShAwYGUIAAjFQFj19HYUABldqdCC4QjzRagJ5HCDbUCkU5eYJo66nMYTKYzFFo6FxaEwLAgBCglQ+MIebbk5GnRGTZEhFLhdI4Mi3SjQzlIAB0mP42O2lBo10ly1W6022225yiODe6MWyAQKhKHklIgkmouYGuAG4aTaad8rL8XP9AfZgcyQAAmKEY3pw5A8jr2MX6npYlH4Qk6WTydgBaMEIXkAA0yCIlrIuKCYCu0ZJyDJ7Wmswz2vIDqsVkW9MZntZqRxEq2QeRouhi2b0pAEdwCjA6yaaZAWBcmygWZysjZKDxOBySpVCjWGxxFvLut9YYNRqEEFN-HNWtI9rDitti3o9CAA)

Comment: Ah, so the `TOutput` can't be inferred from the type bound to `Input<>`'s own type parameter? In other (_JVM Kotlin, for example_) languages, the `TOutput` would be inferred. The objective is, given a type of `TInput`, that it's corresponding `TOutput` would be inferred by the transpiler. Since I'm passing an implementation (_or extended interface_) that binds the `TOutput` type, I figured it would be able to figure it out.

Comment: Nope, I don't think currently there's a way to infer from the output

Comment: At least with JavaScript I don't see a way to change the output of the service based on the callback passed to the subscribe method, so probably there's no need to infer from the return types

Comment: Ah, well that's unfortunate. See my edit for something that comparable that I'm trying to achieve -- I know TypeScript can't support all of the complexities of generics that other languages can, but I was hoping to achieve parity with my added example. And it makes sense that JS can't accomplish that, I just thought the TS transpiler might do some magic to make it enforceable.